# asp.net report viewer error basics : operation not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a handle on the basics of report viewer control in a ASP.net Webforms project with C#.  I'm using Adventure Work reports to get a feel for the basics.

I have a report called SalesOrderNumber under Report Parts on my SQL server

I just want to be able to view it at this point

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote
                ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

                ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;

                // Set the report server URL and report path
                serverReport.ReportServerUrl =
                    new Uri("(!removed!");
                serverReport.ReportPath =
                    "/Report Parts/SalesOrderNumber";

                // Create the sales order number report parameter
                ReportParameter salesOrderNumber = new ReportParameter();
                salesOrderNumber.Name = "SalesOrderNumber";

                salesOrderNumber.Values.Add("SO50750");

                    // Set the report parameters for the report
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(
            new ReportParameter[] { salesOrderNumber });
```

I get back
The operation you are attempting on item '/Report Parts/SalesOrderNumber' is not allowed for this item type. (rsWrongItemType)

Comment: Does the extension not matter? Should it be */Report Parts/SalesOrderNumber.rdl? Also, can the parameter name and the report name be the same? That's what I would try.

Comment: Double check the full report path. Is it the full path? Spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assign full path like

"http://ReportServername/ReportFolderName/reportname.rdlc"

Make sure Report servername, ServerPath , ReportMode ,rendermode also

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but still I found - it needs an answer.

As per my view, we should first check report path that we have set.

The `SSRS ReportPath` setting must specify the full report path.

So if you want to access a report, you should set the below path,

http://YourServerName//ReportServer?/Foldername/ReportName

**Note:** *if you've not created a folder on report server then no need to write **FolderName**. Directly write **ReportName**.*

I would prefer to see below link if you want to access report server using URL.

[Click here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a58b4ca6-129d-45e9-95c7-e9169fe5bba4#feedback)

Hope it would be helpful to others who are facing the same issue.